# Зафиксировать изменения GIT в VSCode

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

Могу ли я зафиксировать изменения определенной строки? То есть, я писал много разного кода в разных частях и мне нужно зафиксировать изменение в определенной строке/строках и написать к этому комментарий.
В обновлениях VSCode я видел, что можно выделять несколько строк и добавлять для них комментарий. Как это сделать? Или я путаю с каким-то другим функционалом?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, действительно в vscode есть такой функционал

```
Git: Stage Selected Ranges
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: [VSCode Multiline comments](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_67#_multiline-comments) я это имел ввиду, это разве не про гит?

Comment: @OliverPatterson VSCode Multiline comments - это про ревью мердж реквестов. Раньше при ревью комент цеплялся к строке, теперь можно цеплять к блоку. А вот если у вас 1000 строк изменений и вы хотите закомитить из них пока что только 5 строк,  то вам нужен Git: Stage Selected Ranges.

Comment: Да,  я уже нашел более удобный способ, нам нужно нажать на файл в категории "changes" и там выйдет сравнении файлов, там можно выделить несколько строк и в контекстном меню будет нужные мне действия.